# show and hide div click on radio button using Alloy ui

Tags: liferay, alloy-ui

Hi I want to show and hide div using alloy ui onclick function of radio button.I mentioned my code as below.please help me to solve this problem.when i clicked on married i want to open one div it has anniversary date and when I click on single it will hide that div.

```
 <aui:field-wrapper name="maritial_status">
        <aui:input checked="<%= true %>" inlineLabel="right" name="maritial_status" type="radio"         value="single" label="single" onClick="javascript:unMarriedStatus();" />
        <aui:input  inlineLabel="right" name="maritial_status" type="radio" value="married" label="married"  onClick="javascript:marriedStatus();" />
    </aui:field-wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by having the function and the div class
so based on the selection call the function which will implicitly create the structure form in div method

function design:
function temp()
{
var chasisno = "";
        $('#dyanamicDivElement').append(chasisno);
}

div structure:

Explanation:
so as per here the function will keep appending the value to the div

hope this solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way:

```
<aui:field-wrapper name="maritial_status">
    <aui:input checked="<%= true %>" inlineLabel="right" name="maritial_status" type="radio" value="single" label="single" onClick="document.getElementById('DIV-ID').style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'block';" />
    <aui:input  inlineLabel="right" name="maritial_status" type="radio" value="married" label="married"  onClick="document.getElementById('DIV-ID').style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';" />
</aui:field-wrapper>
```